# Map a function to a list of variables and overwrite

Tags: python

Imagine I have a simple function that will return a modified value:

```
def foo(x): 
   return x**2
```

I have 4 variables, A - D, in my code that I'd like to run this on.  I'd like it to overwrite A - D in place.  Right now, I'm doing this manually:

```
A = foo(A)
B = foo(B) 
etc...
```

I know that I can do a list comprehension to do this, but then I need to reassign each variable from the list.  Like:

```
new = [foo(x) for x in [A, B, C, D]]
A,B,C,D = new[0], new[1], new[2], new[3]
```

I figure I'm looking for some map function that will overwrite the variable names in place, but not sure which!

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that what you want to do is impossible.

Comment: So Python doesn't have something like:

    map(foo, [A,B,C,D], inplace=True)

Comment: @AdamHuges No and it never will as long as immutable types exist.

Comment: No, that's not how names work in Python (see e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Are you sure `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` should be separate variables in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, they are keyword arguments to a function, but I want them to be explictly shown in the call signature, so not *args or **kwargs.  For each one, I need to basically test if it's a string, and then still have access to them individually as A, B, C, D.  Just got me curious if I'm doing the most pythonic thing, which appears to be the case based on the answer below which is what I did.

Thanks for the materials, I'll read them.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
A,B,C,D = [foo(x) for x in [A, B, C, D]]
```

Comment: Ya, that's the best I could come up with.  I guess it felt a bit clunky because I have to write "A, B, C, D" twice.  I guess I'm just spoiled.  Thanks.

Comment: Or `A, B, C, D = map(foo, (A, B, C, D))` for a more functional style and slightly fewer characters.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Ya, that's what I guess I was looking for in terms of how to use map() in this case.